# C++ Unordered_Map: Receiving "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token" at Compile

Tags: c++, hash, dictionary, compiler-errors, unordered-map

I have an unordered_map (in C++) that pairs an int with an object of class Item.
I initialize my unordered map at the beginning of the file as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;
typedef std::unordered_map<int, Item> MyList;
```

From then on, whenever I try to use MyList, such as in:

```
Item item1;
MyList[12] = item1;
```

I receive an error at said line: "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token" when I compile in the terminal. Any ideas what could be wrong? Below is an other example of how I use it and receive the same or similar error.

```
void itemManager::removeItem(int x)  {
    MyList.erase(x);
}
```

Yields: "error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token"

Please and thanks for the help.

Comment: `MyList[12]` is equivalent to saying `std::unordered_map<int, Item>[12]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyList is a type:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<int, Item> MyList;
```

but you are using it like an object:

```
MyList[12] = item1;
```

Perhaps putting the typedef in there was the mistake.